# PHP Not inserting record due to Null id

Tags: php, mysqli

I want insert record into database using

I have 3 files

> 1. config.php (For database connection )
> 2. function.php (It's for create function of CRUD)
> 3. emp.php (Hear i called function from functions.php)

**1. config.php file**

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password) ;

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$db =mysqli_select_db($conn,"test");    
?>
```

**2. function.php**

```
 <?php
  include('config.php');

function addRecord($table,$columns,$val){
     $insertQuery = "INSERT INTO ".$table." ($columns) VALUES('".$val."')";
     return $insertQuery;
}
    ?>
```

**3. emp.php**

Hear i called `addRecord` function from `function.php` file for add record into database.

```
 <?php
include('config.php');
include('function.php');

$columns= array('employee_name','employee_salary','employee_age');

$values =array('Jack','12000','15');

$val = "".implode("','", $values)."";   
 $col = "`".implode("`,`", $columns)."`";   

addRecord('employee',$col,$val);
```

It's given me warning because of i passed `NULL` in `$values` array so during add record it's display **Warning**: `Missing argument`

`Note`: id is auto increment in DB

When i print query it's showing

```
INSERT INTO employee VALUES('Jack','12000','15');
```

And i used same query in `mysql` it's given `error`

**#1136** - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Someone please help me where i need to change in my code.

Comment: It's not giving you warnings/errors about `addRecord()` requiring three parameters but only getting two?

Comment: I removed second argument.

Comment: Please post the code that shows your insert statement?

Comment: If you wanna skip a field in your insert query (`id` in your case), you need to have your `$columns` array though, defining which fields to enter

Answer (score 1):

Your functions are slightly off.

```
function addRecord($table,$coloumn,$values){
    $insertQuery = "INSERT INTO ".$table." VALUES('".$values."')";      
}
```

This does not return anything, also, the variable `$coloumn` is never used.

I cannot see where your actual mysql insert is happening, but as that function doesn't do anything except assign a string to a variable, it cannot do anything.

`It's given me warning because of i passed NULL in $values array so during add record it's display`

You are calling this function as `addRecord('employee',$val);`, and as you can see, you are passing `$val` where `$coloumn` should be, remove `$coloumn` from the function, and that warning will go away

Also

```
$columns= array('id','employee_name','employee_salary','employee_age');
$values =array(NULL,'Jack','12000','15');
```

should be

```
$columns= array('employee_name','employee_salary','employee_age');
$values =array('Jack','12000','15');
```

Then:

```
function addRecord($table,$values){
    return "INSERT INTO ".$table." VALUES('".$values."')";      
}

$addQuery = addRecord('employee',$val);
```

and use `$addQuery` in your statement.

> ## 1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

This is because you are not specifying which columns to insert, and MySQL knows that there are 4 columns, including the ID, and you are giving it three values.

Your query should be:

```
INSERT INTO employee (employee_name, employee_salary, employee_age) VALUES('Jack','12000','15');
```

Comment: I removed $colomn variable , it was for my debugging purpose.

Comment: Well, that's what caused the problem.

Comment: Record is not inserted when i print query in my sql it's given error of column missed. like #1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: Can you post your insert statement? There is no way your `$insertQuery` is being used as it is not returned in the function.

Comment: I have mentioned in my question also print my query in my quastion

Comment: See my updated answer. Your function `addRecord` does not do anything. If you do not post code to show how this is used, then no one can help you

Comment: I have tried but still not inserting record i have also update my question with updated code.

Answer (score 0):

Change :

```
$columns= array('id','employee_name','employee_salary','employee_age');
$values =array(NULL,'Jack','12000','15');
```

to

```
$columns= array('employee_name','employee_salary','employee_age');
$values =array('Jack','12000','15');
```

Comment: is there any error output ? also you try changing VALUES('".$values."')" to VALUES($values) because you already add ',' in implode. and use function like addRecord("employee","",$values);

Comment: No, there is not error , due to column count record not inserted because of i passed NULL as a id .